# Deleting browser history using Robot Class

Tags: java, selenium, awt, browser-history, awtrobot

I am using Selenium to A/B test my webpage but somehow I am not getting the different experience which I should.
I tried deleting the cookies using

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies() ;
```

but that doesn't seems to work.

A work around i thought was to use [Robot.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) and simulate the browser history delete using keystrokes. Here is the code:

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://booking.com");
    Keyboard keyboard = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getKeyboard();
    keyboard.pressKey(Keys.COMMAND);
    keyboard.pressKey(Keys.SHIFT);
    keyboard.pressKey(Keys.DELETE);
    keyboard.releaseKey(Keys.DELETE);
    keyboard.releaseKey(Keys.SHIFT);
    keyboard.releaseKey(Keys.COMMAND);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    keyboard.pressKey(Keys.ENTER);
    keyboard.releaseKey(Keys.ENTER);
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("done clering history");
}
```

This opens up the history dialog in my firefox browser but does not press the enter key to perform delete and remains stuck. What should be done to perform this task? Is there a way other than Robot to achieve this? Please suggest.

NOTE: I am using Mac and haven't found any substitute for AutoIt.

Comment: have you tried this: `driver.manage().deleteAllCookies()`

Comment: Oh yes. That does not deletes history. Have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you the answer using a windows OS and just Firefox as browser. Follow the same logic for other OS

In Windows FF stores history in a file called places.sqlite under %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles folder. Try to delete that after shutting down your browser.

Trying Robot will introduces uncertainties of locations of mouse clicks and is also a lengthy process.

Write a small Java util (or what ever language you have) and just clean the directory.

virender
http://toolsqa.com

Comment: but how would it delete the history of firefox profile opened via Selenium  as selenium uses a default fresh profile?

Comment: %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles  folder contains all the profiles and each profile has its won history and cache

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SIKULI](http://www.sikuli.org/) instead of AutoIT.

Sikuli automates anything you see on the screen. It uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components. It is useful when there is no easy access to a GUI's internal or source code.

Hope this helps you